# Validate multiple forms with password fields

Tags: jquery, html, validation, jquery-validate

I'm having some validating issues. On my page I have multiple forms, each of the forms can update a password for a particular user. If a user types something, anything into the password field, they must also enter it into the password confirmation field. The password fields are to validated only is the user enters something. Following is what I have below:
The HTML (stripped down for your pleasure)

```
<form action="#" method="post" class="validateUser">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_again">
</form>
```

The jQuery:

```
var entry;
        j$('.validateUser').each(function(index, element) {
            entry = j$(this);
            j$(this).validate({
                rules:{
                    password:{
                        minlength:{
                            depends: entry.find("input[name='password']").val().length > 0,
                            param: 6
                        }
                    },
                    password_again:{
                        minlength: {
                            depends: entry.find("input[name='password']").val().length > 0,
                            param: 6
                        },
                        equalTo: {
                            depends: entry.find("input[name='password']").val().length > 0,
                            param: entry.find("input[name='password_again']").val()
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

The jQuery is currently not working, any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated

Comment: are all of your forms carrying the same field names as `name="password"` and `name="password_again"`?

Comment: @Sina yes I am. All forms have the same name attributes

Comment: Then could you try assigning `id`s to them and then test with `input[id='uniqueid']` and let us know the results (if any)?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using unique id's. I'll give it a try however

Comment: Or you could even have `find("#uniqueid")`? Alright. Just try this, to check if the problem is merely the fact that there are no unique `id`s or specific classes

Comment: Surely if i'm using a unique id I can't have my validate in a .each() loop?

Comment: Nope, then they'd have to be defined one by one.

Comment: Ahh, I'm trying to avoid that. It's dynamic too so I can have just one form to 1000 forms. It needs to be scalable sorry

Comment: You have the `minlength` rule of the `password` field `"depend"` on itself. That does not make any sense.  By default, the `minlength` rule would *not* be evaluated if the field is left empty.

Answer (score -1):

> Try this

```
    // Html Code 
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<form action="#" method="post" class="validateUser">
    passwrod:<input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="PasswordFild1">
   Conform Password: <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_again"  id="PasswordFild2">
</form>


// Jquery Validation

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#PasswordFild2").change(function() {
     var PasswordFild1= $("#PasswordFild1").val();
     var PasswordFild2= $("#PasswordFild2").val();

        if(PasswordFild1 == PasswordFild2 )
        {
           // Then Validate Both Password Match
        }else
        {
            alert('Enter Same password');
         // alert or error mess Print : password not match
        }
          // Check input( $( this ).val() ) for validity here
        });
});
```

Comment: While that does work, it's not what i'm after sorry. It's not scalable, it doesn't use jQuery Validate (needed as I have other fields that need validating)